# javascript link not working

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

This is driving me a bit nutty.  Javascript link should fire function to fill in div.  But not working.

**js**

```
function showNotes(notes,id) {
    var notes = '<form action="editnotes.php" method="post"><textarea>'+notes+'</textarea><input type="hidden" name="id" value="'+id+'"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Notes"></form>';
    var target = 'notebox';
    alert(id);
    document.getElementById(target).innerHTML = notes;
    return false; 
}
```

**html**

```
<a href='#' onclick='showNotes('hi there','143');'><small>Show Notes</small></a>
<div id="notebox"></div>
```

Comment: You need to escape the quotes, as Shredder said. And if you are using Firefox, you can see the syntax errors by using `console errors`. Type CTRL+SHIFT+J.

Comment: Sometimes, a syntax highlight will just let you know where is the problem at, just like in this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enclose the `onclick` attribute value in double quotes, so the single quotes specify a string within your string.

```
onclick="showNotes('hi there','143');"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/77CKx/

Comment: or even better, give the link an id and set the handler from script, then you wouldn't have this problem

Comment: @user1260310 "Did not work" is such a useless thing to say. Which part didn't work? what did you expect, what actually happened? any errors on the console.

Comment: Myjsfiddle was not working  http://jsfiddle.net/7cMez/1/  but I must have some typo or something.  I will use yours Shredder. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Shredder got to the heart of the issue. You have nested quotes. However, inline JS is so not cool. Do it with script and the problem goes away. http://robertnyman.com/2008/11/20/why-inline-css-and-javascript-code-is-such-a-bad-thing/

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" id="shownotes"><small>Show Notes</small></a>
```

**JS**

```
document.getElementById('shownotes').onclick = function() {
   showNotes('hi there', '143');
   return false;
}
```

Comment: did you mean `document.getElementById('shownotes').onclick = function() ..`?

Comment: @Jack Thanks, I did miss that

Comment: By inline JS, you mean even specifying events in html tag is not cool and frowned upon? It is better practice to set events in script? How come? If it is quite an answer, I can post a question about it :)

Comment: @shredder did you see the link I posted in the answer? http://robertnyman.com/2008/11/20/why-inline-css-and-javascript-code-is-such-a-bad-thing/

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are breaking the onclick by using the single apostrophe for your function arguments.

Try

```
<a href='#' onclick="showNotes('hi there','143');"><small>Show Notes</small></a>
```

Comment: Shredder already said that exact same thing. Duplicate answer

Comment: Thanks for the edit. It's my first post and of course I flubbed up. :)

Answer (score 0):

Working code:

```
showNotes = function (notes,id) {
    var notes = '<form action="editnotes.php" method="post"><textarea>'+notes+'</textarea><input type="hidden" name="id" value="'+id+'"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Notes"></form>';
    var target = 'notebox';
    alert(id);
    document.getElementById(target).innerHTML = notes;
    return false; 
}​


<a href='#' onclick="showNotes('hi there','143');"><small>Show Notes</small></a>
<div id="notebox"></div>​
```

You can also view it working here:
http://jsfiddle.net/ZMZGk/13/